# How do I boot into Safe Mode in Ubuntu GCP?

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform

I had an `Ubuntu` in `GCP` and after I installed some services everything was fine. Since this was a paid job, when I finished someone else took over and made some weird stuff which I don't know and created a service loop. Now I can't `SSH` into it because it doesn't even boot up. How can I enter some sort of "safe mode" and disable the service?

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-using-serial-console

Comment: @JohnHanley thanks for response. I try to execute `gcloud compute connect-to-serial-port` but I have this error: `gcloud does not have a fallback Host Key and will therefore terminate the connection attempt. If the problem persists, try updating gcloud and connecting again.`

Comment: Please include more details once you get an error message like that. Edit your question to show what you tried, the error, and what you did to resolve the error.